# How get a specific column from my list of dataframes.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the code I wrote to store all of my cryptocurrency data in it.

```
altcoins2=['BTC','DASH','LTC','NXT',
       'STR','XMR','XRP','ETH',
       'ETC','REP','ZEC','BCH',
      'EOS','SNT','KNC','BAT','LOOM',
      'DOGE','GNT','LSK','SC','ZRX']
actcoin_data = {}

for altcoin in altcoins2:
    coinpair = 'USDT_{}'.format(altcoin)
    crypto_price_df = CryptoData(coinpair)
    crypto_price_df['weekday']=crypto_price_df.index.weekday
    crypto_price_df['change']=crypto_price_df.close.diff()
    actcoin_data[altcoin] = makeData(crypto_price_df)
```

Data is stored as a list of dataframes, i.e., actcoin_data.

Now I want user to type any indicator, e.g., "rsi".
Each dataframe as a column in it named rsi and I want to print all of those columns.

I used:

```
indi = input("which indicator you want \n ")
#user types "rsi" 
for altcoin in altcoins2:
    print(actcoin_data[altcoin].{indi})
```

But its not working. Is there any better way?

Thank you for help.

P.S. CryptoData function is for downloading data from server and makeData refines and makes a data frame.

Comment: Can you try `print(actcoin_data[altcoin][indi])`?

Comment: Technically you have a dictionary of data frames.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, just do:

```
print(actcoin_data[altcoin][indi])
```

Comment: Works fine for me. It really skipped my mind and couldn't find anywhere either.

Comment: @HimanshuSuthar if it solves your problem, accept the answer.

Comment: What docs do you need? You are simply indexing a dictionary which would be a dataframe and then retrieving the series by name. So instead of `df[col]` it becomes `dict[key][col]`